# Available types for Ruby's hash key

Tags: ruby

Must a key be a string or int, or might it be of any object type?

Comment: It takes 30 seconds to try, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @AlanDert [Stack Overflow uses English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118678/how-should-we-handle-wholly-non-english-comments), please only post/comment in English, not any other language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very-very common type is Symbol, which you didn't mention. But it can be any object, really.

```
class Foo; end

f1, f2 = Foo.new, Foo.new

h = {
  f1 => 3,
  f2 => 4
}

h # => {#<Foo:0x007fed4b04bb00>=>3, #<Foo:0x007fed4b04bad8>=>4}
h[f1] # => 3
h[f2] # => 4
```

Comment: @AlanDert, do I know you? :)

Comment: You'd be better off, if you did.

Answer (score 5):

[Not documented?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html)

> [Hash] is similar to an Array, except that indexing is done via arbitrary keys **of any object type**, not an integer index.

(Emphasis mine.)